# How to get ALL entries of google calendar SERIAL event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

How do I get the entries of the serial event? I only get location ("getLocation()"), title ("getTitle()") an the date of creating the serial event. But I cannot find how to get the date an time (e.g. weekly repeating day) and the expiring date of the serial event. I would like to get it and put in a google spreadsheet to get a list of all events of the calender, but it's nonsense to get the weekly repeating events every week, I want to get them as I entered them: a weekly repeating event with day of week, start- and endtime and expiring date. Is that possible to get it with scripts in google? I can't find information. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to retrieve information about recurring events

- [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) returns you general information about an event
- For specific information about **each instance of a recurring event** you need to use [Events: instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances)
- You can use the parameter `fields` to specify the information you want to obtain, e.g. `items(start, end)`
  The output will be:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-07-23T11:00:00+02:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-07-23T12:00:00+02:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
   }
  },
  {
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-07-27T11:00:00+02:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-07-27T12:00:00+02:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
   }
  },
...
```

- To obtain the expiring date you have to use `Events: get` and set `fields` to `recurrence`. This will return you a result like below  provided an end date for the recurrence is specified:

```
"recurrence": [
  "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20200730T215959Z"
 ]
```

Comment: Not easy to insert, but I'll do my best. Google should definetively insert a function like "getRecurrence()" and "isSerial()" to calendar events.